Почему TalkBack на французском языке имеет большую задержку?
Я пытаюсь проверить функциональность Talkback на французском языке (так как приложение поддерживает как английский, так и французский). Когда я перемещаю фокус туда и обратно на английском языке, Talkback срабатывает довольно быстро, но, когда я в настройках девайса переключаю язык на французский (приложение также использует локаль fr), Talkback озвучивает кнопки с большой задержкой - около 10 секунд. То есть, когда пользователь перемещает фокус с одной кнопки на другую, Talkback озвучивает кнопку с задержкой в 10 секунд.
Что я пропускаю тут?

Может он переводит с английского, либо чего-то еще не хватает устройству чтобы fr нормально отрабатывать, вот он его и подгружает постоянно?
